# Spark Streaming into single MySQL table deadlocks

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, spark-streaming, deadlock

I am trying to write a Spark Streaming java application that processes a twitter stream text data and insert the processed data into a mySQL database **(into a single table)**.
While inserting the data into MySQL I encounter multiples Deadlocks, although the partitions should contain non-overlapping keys.

Any idea why I get these deadlocks?

my code:

```
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(windowDuration));
    JavaDStream<String> lines2 = ssc.queueStream(queue,true);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    lines2 = lines2.filter(tweet ->{
        if (tweet.startsWith("RT ") || tweet.startsWith("\"RT ")){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    JavaDStream<String> wordsDaily = lines2.flatMap(
            x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).iterator());
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> pairsDaily = wordsDaily.mapToPair(
            s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCountsDaily = pairsDaily.reduceByKeyAndWindow(
            (i1, i2) -> i1 + i2,new Duration(windowDuration),new Duration(windowDuration),8);
    wordCountsDaily.foreachRDD(k ->{ k.foreachPartition( f-> {
            int counter=0;
            Connection connection =
                    DriverManager.getConnection(url, "****", "*****");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Date now = new Date();
            String date = sdf.format(now);
            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wordsCount"+date+" (`word` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,"
                    +"`occurences` bigint(20) DEFAULT '1',PRIMARY KEY (`word`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

            PreparedStatement stmt2 = connection.prepareStatement(createTable);
            stmt2.executeUpdate();
            stmt2.close();
            String query = "INSERT INTO wordsCount"+date+" (word,occurences) VALUES(?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occurences=occurences+? ";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            while (f.hasNext()) {
                Tuple2<String, Integer> word = f.next();
                stmt.setString(1,word._1);
                stmt.setLong(2, new Long(word._2));
                stmt.setLong(3, new Long(word._2));
                stmt.addBatch();
                counter++;
                if (counter%1000==0) {
                    System.out.println("NUM " +counter);
                    stmt.executeBatch();
                    connection.commit();
                    stmt.clearBatch();
                }
            }
            stmt.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        });

    });
```

You can see my table in the code.

my engine innoDB status:

---

### LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK

2016-12-05 11:11:33 0x7fde2c18d700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:

```
TRANSACTION 1276349, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 19
MySQL thread id 459, OS thread handle 140592201422592, query id 356351 ae.98.2ca9.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com XXX.XX.XXX.174 root update

    INSERT INTO wordsCount20161205 (word,occurences) VALUES('???????',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occurences=occurences+1

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 51 page no 98 n bits 272 index PRIMARY of table `cluster`.`wordsCount20161205` trx id 1276349 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 73 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f; asc ???????;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b000001380e7f; asc k   8  ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800000000000020f; asc         ;;
```

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1276348, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting

```
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
18 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 65 row lock(s), undo log entries 520
MySQL thread id 457, OS thread handle 140592199292672, query id 356692 ae.98.2ca9.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com XXX.XX.XXX.174 root update

    INSERT INTO wordsCount20161205 (word,occurences) VALUES('????????"',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occurences=occurences+1

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 51 page no 98 n bits 272 index PRIMARY of table `cluster`.`wordsCount20161205` trx id 1276348 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 24 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 6; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f; asc ??????;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b000001380946; asc k   8 F;;
 3: len 8; hex 80000000000003cd; asc         ;;

Record lock, heap no 25 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f21; asc ??????!;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b000001380366; asc k   8 f;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000000000000007; asc         ;;

Record lock, heap no 31 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f22; asc ??????";;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b00000138051f; asc k   8  ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000000000000088; asc         ;;

Record lock, heap no 49 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 9; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f2e2e2e; asc ??????...;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b000001380628; asc k   8 (;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000000000000005; asc         ;;

Record lock, heap no 73 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 7; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f; asc ???????;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b000001380e7f; asc k   8  ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800000000000020f; asc         ;;

Record lock, heap no 76 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f22; asc ???????";;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b000001380e29; asc k   8 );;
 3: len 8; hex 8000000000000055; asc        U;;

Record lock, heap no 113 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f; asc ????????;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b0000013811fd; asc k   8  ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800000000000015c; asc        \;;

Record lock, heap no 142 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 10; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f22; asc ?????????";;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b000001380e53; asc k   8 S;;
 3: len 8; hex 800000000000003e; asc        >;;

Record lock, heap no 169 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 11; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f22; asc ??????????";;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bc; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6b0000013804a6; asc k   8  ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000000000000035; asc        5;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 51 page no 98 n bits 272 index PRIMARY of table `cluster`.`wordsCount20161205` trx id 1276348 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 117 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 9; hex 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f22; asc ????????";;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001379bd; asc     y ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6c0000011501ca; asc l      ;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000000000000066; asc        f;;
```

### *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

### TRANSACTIONS

Trx id counter 1276364
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1276364 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 144
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 422067613390672, not started

### 0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)

### FILE I/O

I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
289 OS file reads, 5135 OS file writes, 1023 OS fsyncs

### 0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 11.17 writes/s, 4.00 fsyncs/s

### INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX

Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 184 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 0 buffer(s)

### 148.80 hash searches/s, 933.25 non-hash searches/s

### LOG

Log sequence number 24536188055
Log flushed up to   24536188055
Pages flushed up to 24536188055
Last checkpoint at  24536188046
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes

### 673 log i/o's done, 2.06 log i/o's/second

### BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY

Total large memory allocated 137428992
Dictionary memory allocated 317924
Buffer pool size   8191
Free buffers       6892
Database pages     1115
Old database pages 391
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 264, created 851, written 4200
0.00 reads/s, 2.44 creates/s, 7.58 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 1115, unzip_LRU len: 0

### I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]

### ROW OPERATIONS

0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=10819, Main thread ID=140592264771328, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 169761, updated 186662, deleted 0, read 186670

### 549.01 inserts/s, 240.33 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 240.33 reads/s

## END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT

Comment: Can you be more specific on where the deadlock is at>

Comment: The deadlocks are while inserting the data into the mysql table specified in the code

Comment: User [DataFrameWriter.jdbc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#jdbc(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties)) instead of your own implementation for database insert

Comment: I might do that. but I'm not sure how it solves my deadlocks problem...

Comment: You have multiple instances/sparkbatches of this app running? 1000 random inserts and locks in random order are bound to block another one that does the same. If not, you have to identify the code that interferes here: Check the result from `show engine innodb status`. It will contain a `deadlock` part; identify where the other statement comes from, and post the whole transaction that contains that code. On the other hand: I don't see a reason to use a transaction here at all, you can probably just remove it. If you think/read it's for performance: there are better ways to speed up your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I don't have multiple instances of this app running. 1000 random inserts are doomed to get deadlocks indeed. but using reduceByKey specifying the number of partitions use by default a hash partitioner on the key (the word I'm counting in my case which is also the key of the table) and then i run on each RDD on each partition separately meaning it should not have two transactions on the same row in the MySQL table (because each partition contain non-overlapping set of keys)
What do you mean you don't see a reason to use a transaction at all?could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, you should take a look `show engine innodb status`, it will tell you which code interferes with your inserts. Your approach will probably not lock the way you think it does, but since you can simply look what's wrong, we don't need to guess. Why no transaction? Well, what should your transaction prevent here? You randomly chose to commit after 1000 rows. Could have been 735 rows. Or 26. Or 1. All choices provide the same logical consistency: basically none, unless you commit only once after all rows. So you could just assume it's 1, which equals no transaction at all.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks, Attached to the original post the show engine innodb status

Comment: You have two transaction trying to insert data to the same place. `on duplicate key` will cause gap locks. Here, transaction 2 locked the gap before `???????;;` (e.g. maybe the values between `??????...;;` and `???????;;`). Trans 1 tries to  insert `??????`, which is in that gap. Other direction: `????????";;` and the gap before is locked by trans 1, and trans 2 tries to insert `????????"` directly before that. Deadlock. Still, I don't see a reason for transactions, so maybe just remove them. Or restructure your code (which is a bit more complicated).

Comment: for all i know, the transactions should support faster insertion of the data. But, maybe I'm mistaken. Anyway, I'll try to do it without the transactions and will update upon success failure.

Comment: As I said earlier, there are better ways to speed this up. But first make it working, then make it fast.